# 3rd party Nuget package developers should target which `AspNetCore` package version?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, nuget-package, asp.net5

I have a question described in the title.
In more details: I'm working on a [set of Blazor Components](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components). It has many projects each packaged and published as [Nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Blazor.Components). But of course all projects depends on some `AspNetCore` Nuget packages. Currently using .NET 5 **Version="5.0.0"** packages. But recently Microsoft released **Version="5.0.3"**.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="5.0.0" />
```

So the question is **what is the recommended way to develop and distribute my (3rd) party Blazor Nuget packages?**

- a). **Keep the dependent MS framework packages version as low as possible?** So it works with projects which targets lower versions and might work/or not work with projects which using the latest official MS `AspNetCore` packages,
- b). **Or always update to the latest `AspNetCore` packages to get all bug and security fixes?** But in this case who wants to use my packages probably need to update their projects to the latest version as well? Which they might don't want to do.

I think the question can be relevant not just in case of Blazor Nuget packages. But all 3rd party Nuget package which uses other Microsoft Nuget packages

Comment: I'm not really experienced with this sorta thing, but if i speculate, you'd want to always keep the patch version as high as possible (security updates, minor fixes) and the minor version as low as possible to remain compatible. I'm interested in answers from experts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have different versions for your NuGet packages, each of them targeting different versions of the framework (and different package versions). This way you provide both backward compatibility and an option to integrate the latest features.

At least that's what I think it's the best way to go to make your solutions usable by a larger scale of developers and solutions.